# Jboss logging wrapping my log4j messages

Tags: java, log4j, jboss7.x

I've got a bizarre problem with Log4J under JBoss 7.1.0CR1b (we're just porting to JBoss now, no idea if this happens in older versions). The log lines from my EAR are all being wrapped in an INFO level. So, for example, my log line looks like this:

```
13:09:14,684 INFO  ERROR  CRK TEST!
```

The actual log line is using a log4j Logger.error( "CRK TEST!" ). Where the heck is the extra "INFO" coming from? My guess is the logger message is being wrapped by JBoss's logger somehow since this doesn't happen with pure JBoss container messages, such as:

```
13:08:07,177 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.1.GA
```

I've fiddled with various log4j settings and trying to walk through the debugger, but coming up blank on why this is happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think log4j is writing to stdout which JBoss STDIO takes and outputs as INFO messages to the JBoss Log Manager.

There is a plan to have per deployment logging which could fix this issue, unless your appender is always writing to stdout.

So your best solution would be to look at the appender you're using and see where it's writing. If it's writing to stdout it will always appear like that.

Comment: Yea, this seems to be the case. Older parts of the system are reading a log4j.properties file, which has a ConsoleAppender, which is then caught by JBoss and rewritten with the JBoss console handler. Sadly, I'm not having much luck figuring out how to get them to play nice with each other and removing the old log4j strategy and replacing it with the JBoss version is going to be a bit painful.

Comment: I'm not real familiar with log4j, but could you change the level to NONE for the ConsoleAppender? That might be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your logger is somehow connected to `System.out` and/or `System.err` and that someone (perhaps JBoss, perhaps some other EAR/WAR/...) installs a custom `OutputStream` which wraps everything printed to it into another logger message. Perhaps the missing '[...]' part indicates, that the root logger has been used.

You can test this by printing something directly to bot streams and by fetching the root logger and shove some `INFO`s into it.

Another guess is, that *your* log4j jars somehow conflict with the slf4j stuff propagated by JBoss/Hibernate.

Comment: That missing [...] is rather suspicious to me. Has the op confirmed which level that message is coming out at? A custom appender could help you here - I once wrote one to output more info eg stack trace for every message. Also try -Dlog4j.debug=true which can be informative. Hth and gl